# Emscripten: 'undefined symbol' when calling JavaScript from C/C++; ERROR_ON_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS does not work

Tags: javascript, c++, emscripten

Actually I've two questions, because the common workaround for my initial problem does not work :)

I'm trying to build an Emscripten based library which calls JavaScript functions as described here: https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#implement-a-c-api-in-javascript

Simply put I just implement my C/C++ code against a C-Function, implement that function in a `.js` file and 'link' that file using `--js-library`.

Basically things are working for me except with version EMSDK version 1.38.12 I got a warning when linking the final library:

```
warning: undefined symbol: foo_
```

.. which I don't understand but I could just ignore it. In newer versions of EMSDK the behavior changed and the warnings become errors.

Searching for this error you find you can just add `-s ERROR_ON_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=0` when linking, but this doesn't work (for me) - I still get this error despite I can see this option being added to the linker.

So my questions are:

- how do I make `-s ERROR_ON_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=0` work for me?
- and why do I get this warning in the first place? how do I get rid of it?

Comment: If you're interested in fixing the error and avoiding the tech debt, check your header files to ensure you haven't redefined or mis-defined foo_ or even overloaded foo_ ? Just a guess really.

Comment: I've checked it but unfortunately it's is hardly possible to make a C function declaration not match a JavaScript declaration not match anyway - you just declare a function in C and use it (would not be possible with mismatching signatures). In JavaScript only the function names have to match to make it a valid call